# Eliminate render blocking javascript

Tags: javascript

After running my Wordpress site through Page Speed Insights I'm told that I need to eliminate render blocking javascript. 
So I have moved the vast majority of javascript to just before the closing body tag but the warning still appears in Page Speed Insights.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to resolve this issue please?

The site is http://www.stewartandsonsroofingliverpool.co.uk/

Thanks in advance

Comment: PageSpeed Insights provides instructions. If you click on "eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" in the report, you'll see which scripts and stylesheets are causing the warnings. You'll also see links with more details on how to "remove render-blocking JavaScript" (such as making it asynchronous) and how to "optimize CSS delivery".

Answer (score 2):

You can install a plugin to load your JavaScript asynchronously or try to do it manually adding code to your `functions.php` to load your scripts asynchronously.

This can get you started,

> Warning

loading JavaScript asynchronously will cause several issues with dependencies:

```
/*function to add async to all scripts*/
function js_async_attr($tag){
  //Add async to all  scripts tags
  return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_async_attr', 10 );
```

so you have to check your JS code and update it.

Comment: Setting every JS call to `async` may create dependency issues.

Comment: i will put more warnings, i still want him to dive into this though

Comment: This is 2017, so it's probably safe to use `defer` now instead of `async`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer

Answer (score 1):

## Use `defer` attribute

Instead of converting all script to `async` as [this answer suggested](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257238/111485), it's better to use `defer`. That way, you'll not have dependency errors.

For example, you use a custom script and that script depends on `jQuery`. Since `jQuery` is more likely to be bigger than your custom script, it'll probably end loading before `jQuery`, so your CODE will behave unpredictably.

Instead you can use the following CODE to make sure dependency works:

```
function js_defer_attr( $tag ){
  // add defer to all  scripts tags
  return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_defer_attr', 10 );
```

[Here's more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5250412) about the `defer` attribute.

## Alternative: place script to footer

It's also possible to replace all scripts to footer. Use the following CODE (instead of the above) to place all scripts in the footer:

```
function move_scripts_to_footer() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts' );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9 );
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1 );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5 );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5 );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5 );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'move_scripts_to_footer', -1 );
```

Comment: good trick for placing the scripts in footer, will have to test out this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate render blocking JavaScript very easily by using different plugins, like [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/). Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate Autoptimize.
2. Head to **Settings > Autoptimize**.
3. Check the boxes beside "**Optimize JavaScript Code?**" and "**Optimize
   JavaScript Code?**" options.
4. Click on **Save Changes** button.

You can also use W3 Total Cache plugin to solve the issue. You will find the steps for applying it [right here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-fix-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-of-your-wordpress-website/).